# In C++ how can I make a templated abstract base class covariant with its template parameter?

Tags: c++

I know that `std::shared_ptr` et al emulate covariance by having templated constructors.

But let's say I have an abstract base class that's a simple accessor:

```
template <typename T>
class Reader {
 public:
  virtual const T& Get() const = 0;
};
```

Then if I have a Base and Derived class (it doesn't matter what they do):

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
```

It *should* be safe to receive a `std::unique_ptr<Reader<Derived>>` and pass it around as a `Reader<Base>`.  I think this should work:

```
void Frobnicate(const Reader<Base>& reader) {}

void Run() {
  std::unique_ptr<Reader<Derived>> reader = GetReaderSomehow();
  Frobnicate(*reader);
}
```

But if you do this you'll get an error about `Reader<Derived>` and `Reader<Base>` not being convertible (since, fair enough, they don't inherit from one another):

```
<source>:17:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Reader<Derived>' to 'const Reader<Base>' for 1st argument
   17 | void Frobnicate(const Reader<Base>& reader) {}
```

Since `Reader` is abstract, I can't just add a converting constructor to it because it will try to create an instance of Reader behind the scenes to pass as the const reference.  Similarly if I try to take a `std::unique_ptr<const Derived<Base>>&` as the argument to Frobnicate, the non-convertibility makes the unique pointers non-convertible.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: How about adding `using base = Base;` to `Derived` (and to any derived class you'll ever use with this), then inheriting `Reader<T>` from `Reader<typename T::base>` if it exists? But this means you can't have >1 base per derived class.

Comment: To be really pedantic, ofcourse it matters what the derived class does. It should follow the Liskov substitution principle ;) Also I would expect the derived class to be not implement Reader<Base> but some kind of Reader<T> ... All in all I just have the feeling your mixing too much static/dynamic polymorphism in your design to really be able to use the "power" of either strategy.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` can only mimic what a normal pointer does. If you can't convert `Reader<Derived>*` to `Reader<Base>*`, you can't do it with the shared pointer either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replicate the inheritance structure of `Base`/`Derived` in `Reader`, i.e. `Reader<Derived>` must be derived from `Reader<Base>`.

The language doesn't offer any way to obtain a list of base classes of a given class, so the only way I see this working in general is to add the specializations manually, i.e. after the definition of `Derived` add

```
template<> struct Reader<Derived> : Reader<Base> { using Reader<Base>::Reader; };
```

It can be simplified a bit by using a trait instead, which `Reader` could then use to lookup the base classes.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I don't need it to work in general, in this particular case I do know what my Base and Derived classes will be so I might just do this.

Comment: This is tricky because anything inheriting from Reader<Derived> would have a const Base& Get() method to overload and not know it.  I'd have to redirect that in the specialization _but_ you can't overload just by return type :'(

Comment: @gct That shouldn't be necessary. The return types would be covariant. You could add `const Derived& Get() const = 0;` so that a user of `Get` on `Reader<Derived>` won't unexpectedly get a base class reference, but it will not be an overload. It will still override the `Get` in the base.

Comment: @gct But I realized that this can only work after the definition of `Derived`, so I removed the recommendation to do it before the definition of `Derived`.

Comment: I fudged a little bit in my example, Get() actually returns a std::unique_ptr<T> which breaks the covariance =(   What I ended up doing is modifying my Get() method to take a T* that gets populated, then I can implement Reader<Derived> : Reader<Base> and then I can implement the covariance myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make another `Reader` that points to the `Reader<Derived>` and is a `Reader<Base>`:

```cpp
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct DerivedReaderRef : Reader<Base> {
    const Reader<Derived>& r;

    constexpr DerivedReaderRef(const Reader<Derived>& r) noexcept : r(r) {}

    const Base& Get() const override {
        return r.Get();
    }
};

void Run() {
  std::unique_ptr<Reader<Derived>> reader = GetReaderSomehow();
  Frobnicate(DerivedReaderRef<Base, Derived>{*reader});
}
```

You could make it easier to use and hold a generic conversion function and add helper functions so the syntax could look like `readerCast(*reader, [](const Derived& d) -> const Base& { return d; })` or `readerDowncast<Base>(*reader)`. This still unfortunately has to name the base class (and has some ownership/lifetime issues if you try to hold a `DerivedReaderRef`)

---

If there are very few and a known amount of classes for which you use `Reader` for, you could create a shadow template hierarchy:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Reader {
    virtual const T& Get() const = 0;
};

template <>
struct Reader<Derived> : Reader<Base> {
    const Derived& Get() const = 0;
};
```

So now a `Reader<Derived>` is-a `Reader<Base>`, but you have to replicate this for every class used by `Reader`.

It would be easiest to write these `Reader` specializations directly after the `Derived` class's definition to ensure you never accidentally write `Reader<Derived>` without having the specialization declared (which would be an ODR violation)

Comment: I'm playing around with the shadow template hierarchy now and I think the return type being different in Derived::Get() and Base::Get() is problematic.